# cannot request ajax when using bootsrap

Tags: html, ajax

[image]im new to website programming, i dont really know what is the problem but every time i add this code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var LiveHelpSettings = {};
LiveHelpSettings.server = 'chat.xxx.net';
LiveHelpSettings.embedded = true;
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(window).ready(function() {
      LiveHelpSettings.server = LiveHelpSettings.server.replace(/[a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:\/\/|\/livehelp\/*(\/|[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@\/]*(?![a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]))|\/*$/g, '');
      var LiveHelp = document.createElement('script'); LiveHelp.type = 'text/javascript'; LiveHelp.async = true;
      LiveHelp.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + LiveHelpSettings.server + '/livehelp/scripts/jquery.livehelp.min.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(LiveHelp, s);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

my dropdown menu wont work at all,..but live chat is work

but when i remove that code, all my elements work fine

i use bootstrap which i download from

[download bootstrap](http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/dashgum)

can anybody help me??

**UPDATE**
it works fine when i open it using chrome..

Comment: here is the complete code

http://expirebox.com/download/c988eedc91003401c653a35329762699.html

Comment: do you get any error in your browser console ?

Comment: i have update the post

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are trying to perform some AJAX onto a different domain than the origin of the script. And the same origin policy disallows that !
[Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: you should use JSONP : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
it allows data requests between different domains. AJAX does not